# Oracle SQL group by not functioning correctly

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to group this by name and id, it still shows duplicates. How could I combine these 5 names into one?

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME, OI.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, SUM(OI.QUANTITY), SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNIT_PRICE)
FROM CUSTOMERS C 
INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI ON O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID = 44
GROUP BY OI.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME
ORDER BY SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNIT_PRICE) DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want one row per customer:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME, SUM(OI.QUANTITY), SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNIT_PRICE)
FROM CUSTOMERS C INNER JOIN
     ORDERS O 
     ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID INNER JOIN
     ORDER_ITEMS OI
     ON O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID = 44
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME
ORDER BY SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNIT_PRICE) DESC;
```

The columns more specific to the orders should not be in the `SELECT` or `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This works, however I'd need the more specific ones to stay in the select statement. It's simply not possible I'm assuming?

Comment: @Zelkop . . . Which values do you want?  Each row has different values, which is why you are get multiple rows in your query.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, you're getting what you asked for. My best guess, however, is that you want the individual name, ID, and Order date fields, but that you then want a subtotal for each customer. The way to do this is with ROLLUP:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME, OI.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE,
               SUM(OI.QUANTITY) AS ITEM_QUANTITY,
               SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNIT_PRICE) AS EXTENDED_PRICE
          FROM CUSTOMERS C 
          INNER JOIN ORDERS O
            ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
          INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI
            ON O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
          WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID = 44
          GROUP BY ROLLUP (C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME, OI.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE))
  WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL AND
        NAME IS NOT NULL AND
        (ORDER_DATE IS NOT NULL OR
         (ORDER_DATE IS NULL AND ORDER_ID IS NULL))
  ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, EXTENDED_PRICE DESC
```

This produces a result of

```
CUSTOMER_ID NAME            ORDER_ID    ORDER_DATE  ITEM_QUANTITY   EXTENDED_PRICE
44          Jabil Circuit                           3772            3334311.72
44          Jabil Circuit   92          28-AUG-15   790             1050939.97
44          Jabil Circuit   69          17-MAR-17   581             755093.92
44          Jabil Circuit   10          24-JAN-17   883             621052.99
44          Jabil Circuit   29          14-AUG-17   831             508588.59
44          Jabil Circuit   82          16-DEC-16   687             398636.25
```

The WHERE clause in the outer query just gets rid of some unwanted sub-total lines - try taking the WHERE clause out to see what it eliminates from the result set.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a8943c4e14270d51472323dd0a42b4c)